# Find all functions holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash\{0,+1,-1\},$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all function holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash\{0,+1,-1\},$ such that $f$ have pole order 2 in point $z=0,$ pole order 1 in $z=1$ and $z=-1,$ and $\lim _{z \rightarrow \infty} z^{3} f(z)=2$

---

From assumptions from task. We have that 
$f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z^2(z-1)(z+1)}$

But  I don't know how to use fact about $\lim _{z \rightarrow \infty} z^{3} \frac{g(z)}{z^2(z-1)(z+1)}=2$

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z^2(z-1)(z+1)}$ with an *entire* function $g$.
$$
 g(z) =  \bigl( z(z-1)(z+1)f(z)\bigr) \cdot z \sim 2z
$$
for $z \to \infty$ implies that $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most one, so that $g(z)=  2z+c$ for some constant $c \in \Bbb C$. It remains to figure out the possible values for $c$ ...

Comment: For any $c\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Surajit: I did not claim that. I think there is no harm in leaving *some* work to the question author :)

Answer (score 1):

We have $\lim _{z \rightarrow \infty} z^{3} \frac{g(z)}{z^2(z-1)(z+1)}=\lim _{z \rightarrow \infty}\frac{g(z)}{z}=2$. Since $g$ is entire, so the last equality implies $g(z)=a+2z$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C}$. But $f$ has a pole of order 2 at $z=0$, and pole of order 1 at $z=\pm 1$, which implies $g(0)g'(0)g(1)g(-1)\neq 0$, and in terms of $a$ this means $a\not\in\{0,\pm 2\}$. Hence $f(z)=\frac{a+2z}{z^2(z-1)(z+1)}$ for $a\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,\pm 2\}$.